# ¿Cómo hago para hacer un conversor de unidades de temperatura en javascript usando solo botones y condicionales if - else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if, botón, entrada

Estoy realizando un curso de javascript y me han pedido realizar un conversor de unidades de temperatura de Celcius a Fahrenheit y a Kelvin pero solo usando botones, campos y condicionales if-else.

He intentado hacerlo pero me he estancado.

Llevo hecho esto:

```js
  var = C = 0;
  var = K = 0;
  var = F = 0;
 
      //Fahrenheit a Celsius   C =(F-32)*5/9
      function Fahrenheit_Celsius() {
        
        F = document.getElementById("cantidad").value

        C =(F-32)*5/9;
       
       Mensaje = ("Celsius: " + C);
        
      }
       
     //Fahrenheit a Kelvin K = (F-32)*5/9 +273
      function Fahrenheit_Kelvin() {

        F = document.getElementById("cantidad").value

        K = (F-32)*5/9 +273;

        Mensaje = ("Kelvin: " + K);
        
      }
      
      //Celsius a Fahrenheit  F = C*9/5+32
      function Celsius_Fahrenheit() {

        C = document.getElementById("cantidad").value

        F =C*9/5+32;

        Mensaje = ("Fahrenheit " + F);
        
      }
     
     //Celsius a Kelvin K=C+273
     function Celsius_Kelvin() {

       C = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

       K=C+273;

       Mensaje = ("Celsius: " + K);

      }
      
                   
      //Kelvin a Fahrenheit   F= (k-273)9/5+32
      function Kelvin_Fahrenheit() {

         K = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

         F= (K-273)*9/5+32;

         Mensaje = ("Fahrenheit: " + F );
        
      }

       //Kelvin a Celsius C=K-273
      function Kelvin_Celsius() {

      K = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

      C=K-273;

      Mensaje = ("Celsius: " + C );
        
      }
       
       }

  } else {

    Mensaje = "Error"
  } 
  
}
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Conversor de Temperatura</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <strong>Conversor de Temperatura</strong><br>

  <br>Ingrese valor a convertir<br>
  <input type="number"  id ="cantidad" name="numero">
  <div id="Mensaje"></div><br>

  Seleccione la conversion que quiere hacer:<br><br>

<button onclick="Fahrenheit_Celsius()">Fahrenheit a Celsius</button>
<button onclick="Fahrenheit_Kelvin()">Fahrenheit a Kelvin</button><br><br>
<button onclick="Celsius_Fahrenheit()">Celsius a Fahrenheit</button>
<button onclick="Celsius_Kelvin()">Celsius a Kelvin</button><br><br>
<button onclick="Kelvin_Fahrenheit()">Kelvin a Fahrenheit</button>
<button onclick="Kelvin_Celsius()">Kelvin a Celsius</button><br>


</body>
</html>
```

La pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer para incluir las condicionales? Porque estoy obligado a utilizarlas

Comment: Tienes un error tipográfico, no puedes declarar var con un = por delante del nombre de la variable.

Comment: Lo primero, se ordenado con tu código, formatealo y ponlo bonito intenta seguir la [guía](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).`

Lo segundo, tienes un error en como defines las variables en javascript, mirate este [documento](http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_3/variables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas, he modificado y corregido tus errores tipográficos. El resultado seria tal que así:
El script como he visto que estás importando el jQuery también te lo he puesto en el ejemplo:

> EDICIÓN: Añadí las cláusulas if-elseif que no había implementado

**JAVASCRIP**

```
var C = 0;
var K = 0;
var F = 0;

      function convertir(e) {

      //Fahrenheit a Celsius   C =(F-32)*5/9
        if (e.target.name == "Fahrenheit-a-Celsius") {
       // CON JQUERY
        F = $('#cantidad').val();
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
        F = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

        C = (F-32)*5/9;

        // CON JQUERY
       $('#mensaje').text("Celsius: " + C); 
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = "Celsius: " + C;

        }

        //Fahrenheit a Kelvin K = (F-32)*5/9 +273
        else if (e.target.name == "Fahrenheit-a-Kelvin"){
            // CON JQUERY
        K = $('#cantidad').val();
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
         K = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

        K = (F-32)*5/9 +273;

        // CON JQUERY
       $('#mensaje').text("Kelvin: " + K);
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = ("Kelvin: " + K);

        }
            //Celsius a Fahrenheit  F = C*9/5+32
            else if (e.target.name == "Celsius-a-Fahrenheit"){
       // CON JQUERY
        C = $('#cantidad').val();
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
         C = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

        F =C*9/5+32;

        // CON JQUERY
       $('#mensaje').text("Kelvin: " + F);
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = ("Fahrenheit: " + F);

        }

        //Celsius a Kelvin K=C+273
            else if (e.target.name == "Celsius-a-Kelvin"){
       // CON JQUERY
        C = $('#cantidad').val();
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
         C = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

       K=C+273;

        // CON JQUERY
       $('#mensaje').text("Celsius: " + K);
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = ("Celsius: " + K);  

        }

        //Kelvin a Fahrenheit   F= (k-273)9/5+32
            else if (e.target.name == "Kelvin-a-Fahrenheit"){

        // CON JQUERY
        K = $('#cantidad').val();
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
         K = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

         F= (K-273)*9/5+32;

        // CON JQUERY
       $('#mensaje').text("Fahrenheit: " + F );
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = ("Fahrenheit: " + F );

        }

         //Kelvin a Celsius C=K-273
        else{
        // CON JQUERY
        K = $('#cantidad').val();
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
         K = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;

        C=K-273;

        // CON JQUERY
       $('#mensaje').text("Celsius: " + C );
       // CON JAVASCRIPT PURO
       document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = ("Celsius: " + C );
        }
      }
```

> **NOTA:** Tendrás que elegir entre javascript puro o jQuery.

En tu HTML no he tocado casi nada, solo los nombres de las funciones que las he pasado a minúsculas.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Conversor de Temperatura</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

      <strong>Conversor de Temperatura</strong><br>

      <br>Ingrese valor a convertir<br>
      <input type="number" id ="cantidad" name="numero">
      <div id="mensaje"></div><br>

      Seleccione la conversion que quiere hacer:<br><br>

<button onclick="convertir(event)" name="Fahrenheit-a-Celsius">Fahrenheit a Celsius</button>
<button onclick="convertir(event)" name="Fahrenheit-a-Kelvin">Fahrenheit a Kelvin</button><br><br>
<button onclick="convertir(event)" name="Celsius-a-Fahrenheit">Celsius a Fahrenheit</button>
<button onclick="convertir(event)" name="Celsius-a-Kelvin">Celsius a Kelvin</button><br><br>
<button onclick="convertir(event)" name="Kelvin-a-Fahrenheit">Kelvin a Fahrenheit</button>
<button onclick="convertir(event)" name="Kelvin-a-Celsius">Kelvin a Celsius</button><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```

La función quedaría como una solo función y se diferenciaría la cada función en la condición ***if-elseif*** por el nombre del botón en este ejemplo.
Prueba de esta forma y nos cuentas.

Comment: una pregunta ¿para que sirve target?

Comment: Hola @condor12, el target es el elemento que ha ejecutado ese evento. En este caso es cada el botón que se ha pulsado. `event.target.name` Selecciona de la función (convertir()) el nombre del elemento que ha disparado el evento, en este caso un `<button>`.